# How to close a modal box after form submit?

Tags: html, css, forms

I am using the css modal box described by Paul R.Hayes here - http://www.paulrhayes.com/experiments/modal/

I have inserted a form into the modal box. The form target is in an iframe which is hidden on the same page. I want to close the modal window as soon as the form submits. But the form should be processed within the iframe (hidden).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You accidentally made two unregistered accounts. I've merged them, you can now edit your question and leave comments under answers on your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the modal window is closed by any url linking to the #close html fragment.

Therefore adding the following code to the submit handler of your form should close the modal on submission.

```
<form ... onsubmit="window.location.assign('#close')">
```

Comment: @Ryan McCrossan, Thanks. Yes. This modal box is solely made of css3. your onsubmit solution worked. It was simple but did not strike me. I was thinking of a redirect.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the close button of the modal button calls a Javascript function. For instance "CloseModal()".
In your form tag, you can use the following code to call that function:

```
<form name="myform" action="myconfpage.extension" target="iframe" onSubmit="CloseModal();">
```

This will call the close function on submitting of the form.

Comment: I thought the same, however it appears this modal window is created solely by CSS.